# Add Retrofit @Query for value in the middle of link

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I have this link which contains different parameters, I want to search more through making a new request, which will require passing `id_ruta`. I tried to pass it as parameter, but it is not working, how can I do this?

- This is the link

  ```
  https://www.samplesite.com/index.php/Ruta/get_pax_ruta?id_ruta=285774&key=5786938888
  ```
- This is my code

  ```
  @GET("Ruta/get_pax_ruta?{id_ruta}&key=5786938888")
     suspend fun getRouteDetails(
         @Path("id_ruta") id_ruta : String
     ) : RouteDetailsModel
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
 @GET("Ruta/get_pax_ruta?{id_ruta}&key=5786938888")
suspend fun getRouteDetails(
    @Path("id_ruta") id_ruta : String
) : Call<RouteDetailsModel>
```